# Suppressed keyboard messages don't die

Tags: winapi

I regularly use a certain application (which is closed-sourced, single-threaded, 32-bit, native) that predates such niceties as configurable key bindings. It does support plug-ins, though, so I'm making one to provide the missing feature.

I'm using `SetWindowsHookEx` to add a `WH_KEYBOARD` hook. Some key presses go through unchanged, and others get suppressed and handled manually. For the latter case I'm (as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to suggest) just returning 1 and ignoring the output of `CallNextHookEx`. That works in most cases, but there's at least one case--Ctrl+D--that the application is still handling even though I told it not to.

Is there something more/different I should be doing to squash that keystroke?

Maybe relevant: normally I get both an `HC_NOREMOVE` and an `HC_ACTION` version of each message, but for Ctrl+D I only get the `HC_ACTION` version.

C# source:

```
    private IntPtr ProcessWindowsMessage(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (code < 0 || code == HC_NOREMOVE)
        {
            return Win32.CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, code, wParam, lParam);
        }

        Keys key = GetKeyFromWParam(wParam);
        Keys keyCombo = key | GetCurrentModifiers();
        var isKeyDownEvent = IsKeyDownEvent(lParam);

        var handled = stateMachine.Add(keyCombo, isKeyDownEvent);
        if (handled)
        {
            Win32.CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, code, wParam, lParam);
            return LResultHandled;
        }
        else
        {
            return Win32.CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, code, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    private static readonly IntPtr LResultHandled = new IntPtr(1);
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't say to return non-zero **instead** of calling `CallNextHookEx`. You should **always** call `CallNextHookEx`, because *"other applications that have installed `WH_KEYBOARD` hooks will not receive hook notifications and may behave incorrectly as a result."*

Comment: Fair point. I've changed it in my code and updated the source listing above.

Comment: This issue appears to only happen when a particular other plug-in is also enabled. Possibly we're both trying to do similar things but just not playing nicely together.

Comment: Actually the documentation implies that if `code` is >= zero **and** your hook processes the message, you do not have to call `CallNextHookEx`. Typically unclear Microsoft documentation but that's my understanding of it.

Comment: Are you sure that the other "pluggin" don't poll the keyboard and just uses GetAsynchKeyState to check if some keys are pressed? If so this plugin don't uses those messages you want to track and want to ignore.

Comment: Now that you point that out... yeah, I suppose it could be doing that.

Comment: At this point I suspect that the answer is "no, the other plugin is going to process the keystroke no matter what I do". Meta-question: Is it good form to somehow close this question, or should I just leave it open, or what?